# Plot histogram and fit it with exponential fit using python and imported data from excel file

Tags: python, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram in python by importing data from an excel file.
Also, the histogram needs to be fitted with an exponential function.
How can I do this plotting and fitting procedure?

Comment: can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

For plotting just [use](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) `plt.hist` and your data

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data for test
data = [random.randint(1,20) for i in range(20)]

n, x, _ = plt.hist(data)

bin_centers = 0.5*(x[1:]+x[:-1])
plt.plot(bin_centers,n);
```

for fitting you can extract bins centers and try to fit it [with](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) `curve_fit`:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# some exponential function
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, bin_centers, n, bounds=(0, [3., 1., 0.5]))
# bounds are variable, so you can change them as you wish

plt.plot(bin_centers, n, label='data')
plt.plot(bin_centers, func(bin_centers, *popt), label='fit')
plt.legend()
```